# Laravel y vueJs consumo de api

Tags: vue.js

Hola amigos es que me gustaria consumir un api de laravel con vue. Digamos que me funciona bien con un componente pero cuando quiero usar uns egundo componente no funciona no se que estoy haciendo realmente.
app.js

```
 Vue.component('articulo', require('./components/Articulo.vue').default);
    Vue.component('usuarioArticulo', require('./components/UsuarioArticulo.vue').default);
     const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        componenta
    });
```

tengo los dos archivos aaparte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que puse con mayuscula el componente usuarioArticulo, y se arreglo poniendo usuarioarticulo